# Javascript: dropdown, get first element value LIKE?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Given a dropdown with an unknown number of option elements:

```
<select id="ddlDropDown">
    <option value="text1">Some text</option>
    <option value="text2">Some text</option>
    <option value="text3">Some text</option>
    ...
    <option value="textN">Some text</option>
```

And given a textbox where I can type in a value:

```
<input type=text id="txtTextBox" onkeyup="selectDDL();"/>
```

And given the script function:

```
function selectDDL(){
    var txtElem = document.getElementById("txtTextBox");
    var ddlElem = document.getElementById("ddlDropDown");

    var typedText = txtElem.value;
    //magic happens here

}
```

How do I, using purely javascript, get select the first option matching LIKE the text in the text box without iterating through the entire collection?

That is to say, assume that I have 500 dropdown option elements with random values between 500 and 1500, how do I get and select the first option (in the list, not in order) that matches what the user has typed so far?

So if their were three items: 1030, 1012, and 1013 in the dropdown and the user types:

1: 1030 is selected.

10: 1030 is still selected

101: 1012 is selected

1013: 1013 is selected

Clarification: without iterating the collection and similar to jquery's ^= operator

Comment: So you want a single item return?

Comment: That is correct. I want the first item in the list of options that matches the text the user has typed in. I assume that there's a string.contains or similar that will grab the first one without being strict about "must match all" - just matches the first.

Comment: look up how str.indexOf works.  You can use that to go through the string until you find one that contains what you're looking for.

Comment: That's the question. I want to do this without iterating through the whole thing. It'd be an extremely simple task if I had access to jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to use `^=`, just use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the [attribute prefix selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
var texts = document.querySelectorAll("[value^='text']");
console.log(texts);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlDropDown">
  <option value="text1">Some text</option>
  <option value="text2">Some text</option>
  <option value="text3">Some text</option>
  <option value="textN">Some text</option>
  <option value="notText">123456</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix FYI: Did you notice the notes in my answer where you will need to escape the special characters or your users are going to generate errors?

Comment: I can try-catch all errors without issue. All values in the dropdown options are numbers. If they type something else, that's their problem :) But this is something I will keep in mind for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a starts with attribute selector. Only issue with the code is I am not escaping any of the special characters from the selector. So if the user enters in `'` it will blow up.

```js
document.querySelector("#x").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  //code to filter out the options
  var txt = this.value;
  var opts = document.querySelectorAll("#ddlDropDown option[value^='" + txt + "']");
  //code to display the options for demo
  var out = Array.prototype.slice.call( opts ).map(function (x) {return x.value});
  document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = out.join("<br/>");
});
```

```html
 
<select id="ddlDropDown">
    <option value="text1">Some text</option>
    <option value="text2">Some text</option>
    <option value="text3">Some text</option>
    <option value="text11">Some text</option>
    <option value="text21">Some text</option>
    <option value="text31">Some text</option>
</select>

<input type="textbox" id="x">

<p></p>
```

Comment: the requirements say no jquery at all

Comment: Well it has no jQuery now, code is basically exactly the same code minus the jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `string#indexOf` method to find out if there's a match.

```
function selectDDL() {
    var txtElem = document.getElementById("txtTextBox");
    var ddlElem = document.getElementById("ddlDropDown");

    var typedText = txtElem.value;
    var options = document.querySelectorAll("#ddlDropDown option");
    var matches = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (options[i].innerHTML.indexOf(typedText) == 0) {
            matches.push(options[i]);
        }
    }
    matches[0].setAttribute("selected", "selected");

}
```

Comment: And without iterating the entire collection? Don't have to iterate with jQuery

Comment: You can't iterate through the collection using `filter` because it's not an array

Comment: You can convert it to an array. Look at the map line in my code.

Comment: dave's answer is exactly what I was looking for. "querySelectorAll" and the abilty to use ^= without jquery was the two pieces of knowledge I was missing.

Comment: I used querySelectorAll and no jquery

Answer (score 0):

Those who rely on a selector with [value^=...] will find an option by its value attribute, not by its text.
There is no CSS selector for selecting an option by its text. jQuery supports "has" and "contains", but uses iteration to implement those features.

Just for a fun alternative, but probably not advisable: innerHTML is slow and this will go wrong when the select tag has other tags inside than the options:

```
var html = ddlElem.innerHTML; 
var idx = html.indexOf('>'+typedText);
ddlElem.selectedIndex = idx === -1
    ? -1
    : html.substr(0, idx).match(/\<option/g).length - 1;
```

Comment: This is actually okay since the value of each option is, simply put, a customer ID that the user knows. So searching by tag attribute is just fine. If, however, I needed to search by text, I'd have to say that innerHTML is the alternative I'd need to use. Thankfully, this is not the case.